# How can I attaching an additional EBS volume to EC2 from Data Pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2, amazon-data-pipeline, aws-data-pipeline

I need to attached an additional EBS volume to my ec2 instance from data pipeline. I think currently data pipeline service does not support an option to specify ebs volumes to attach to a ec2 resource. are there any way to do that using data pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly do that from data pipeline itself. You can write a shell script to do that and add that script in ScriptArgument of ShellCommandActivity.